# OpenCV DescriptorExtractor returns empty

Tags: ios, opencv, object-detection, orb

I am trying to do object detection using OpenCV on iOS. I'm using [this code sample from the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_features2d.html).

Here's my code:

```
Mat src = imread("src.jpg");
Mat templ = imread("logo.jpg");

Mat src_gray;
cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

Mat templ_gray;
cvtColor(templ, templ_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

int minHessian = 500;

OrbFeatureDetector detector(minHessian);

std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;

detector.detect(src_gray, keypoints_1);
detector.detect(templ_gray, keypoints_2);

OrbDescriptorExtractor extractor;

Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;

extractor.compute(src_gray, keypoints_1, descriptors_1);
extractor.compute(templ_gray, keypoints_2, descriptors_2);
```

The problem is on the line `extractor.compute(src_gray, keypoints_1, descriptors_1);` which leaves `descriptors_1` always empty.

`src` and `templ` are not empty.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Is keypoints_1 empty?

Comment: yes, `keypoints_1` is empty.

Comment: Then you can't calculate descriptors and therefore, descriptors_1 is empty.

Comment: OK, so why would `descriptors_1` be empty if the Mats is there?

Comment: First, you detect keypoints in your image using detect(). Then, you describe these keypoints in the image using compute(). The result is stored in descriptors_1/2. But if there are no keypoints, there is nothing to describe. Therefore, descriptors_1 is empty.

Comment: Right, but why would that happen if the Mat is not empty?

Comment: Which Mat is not empty? If you mean the input image is not empty, that can happen because the detector does not find any keypoint. Maybe because there are no salient points in it or the parameters of the detector (e.g. minHessian) is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think that if you want to use feature detectors and descriptors you must inform yourself of how they work. 
You can see this topic, the answer of 'Penelope' explains everything better than I can do:
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10423/why-do-we-use-keypoint-descriptors

After the first step I think you should know better how the ORB detector/descriptor works (if u really want to use it), what are its parameters, etc. For this u can check the opencv documentation and the ORB paper:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html
https://www.willowgarage.com/sites/default/files/orb_final.pdf

I say this because you set  'minHessian' parameter on ORB detector when  ‘minHessian’ is actually a parameter from the SURF detector.

Anyway the problem of your code is not that. Try to load ur images like the example you are following:

```
Mat src = imread("src.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat templ = imread("logo.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
```

Then detect the keypoints:

```
detector.detect(src, keypoints_1);
detector.detect(templ, keypoints_2);
```

and now check if keypoints_1 and keypoints_2 are not empty. If they are go for the descriptor extraction! It should work

Hope this helps